# Como puedo escribir esta ecuacion en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**x** y **z** son parametros o inputs y la funcion debe return (regrsar) **y**

Comment: Te recomiendo leer sobre el modulo Math (https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/math.html) y buscar por Google algunos tutoriales sobre inputs, operaciones aritméticas y funciones en Python. O recurrir a los libros que te dieron.

Answer (score 2):

El código sería el siguiente utilizando el módulo `math` de Python:

```
import math

def operacion(x, z):
    return (math.log(z - x, 10)) / (math.pi * math.factorial(x))
```

He supuesto que la base del logaritmo es 10, si no es esa puedes cambiar el 10 en `math.log(z - x, 10)`.

Comment: Es bueno querer ayudar sin embargo te comento que las preguntas que solo exponen un enunciado de tarea sin mayor trabajo por parte de quien expone la duda no son bien recibidas y terminan cerradas

Comment: Por otro lado yo te recomendaría para que tu aporte sea valorado desde una perspectiva distinta expongas: ¿por qué el módulo math?